# Relationships between custom fields and taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have a custom post type named `products` and a taxonomy named `product_categories`. There are some parent and child terms under `product_categories`.

I want to add `min_price` and `max_price` fields for each term in product page.

With Wordpress's `add_post_meta` function, I can add minimum and maximum prices as a custom field for each product, but I have no idea how to do relationship between these prices and taxonomy terms.

What should I do for that?

---

Thanks for your reply Anh, but my problem still continues with `add_term_meta` function.

For example:

`$term_id = '10';` (Kitchen)

`add_term_meta ($term_id, 'min_price', '99', true);`

In this example, I am adding a minimum price $99 for Kitchen term. But I want to add this price for each posts.

For example:

- Post 1 / Term: Kitchen / Min price: 99
- Post 2 / Term: Kitchen / Min price: 250
- Post 3 / Term: Kitchen / Min price: 320
- Post 4 / Term: Kitchen / Min price: 59

That's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress supports adding meta to taxonomy terms via `add_term_meta` function. You have to hook to the term edit page, showing the form and use `add_term_meta` to add meta values.

As there is a lot of work, I'd suggest using a custom fields framework like [Meta Box](https://metabox.io). It supports term meta via [MB Term Meta](https://metabox.io/plugins/mb-term-meta/) extension.